# How to tell an server that client supports SPDY protocol?

Tags: client-server, network-protocols, spdy

What is necessary to tell a server that a Webclient supports the [SPDY protocol](http://dev.chromium.org/spdy)? On what level (TCP/IP, HTTP, ...) do I transmit this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the client performs the SSL handshake the server needs to advertise spdy via the NPN extension. Here are a couple of links for more details:

- http://dev.chromium.org/spdy/spdy-protocol/spdy-protocol-draft2#TOC-Server-Advertisement-of-SPDY-throug1
- https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-agl-tls-nextprotoneg-00.html

Comment: I don't think the OP knows how lucky he is to have had a guy of your calibre answer his question lol. Just was about to watch your video igrigorik. Thanks for all you do.